# ¿Cómo llamo el método de la clase nota a la clase nota2 en Java?

Tags: java, método

```
public class Nota {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nota objNota=new Nota();
        objNota.notaExamen();
        {
    }


    }
double notaExamenTotal;


public void notaExamen () {
    double notaExamenTotal=(6);
    System.out.println(notaExamenTotal);



if(notaExamenTotal == 10) {
    System.out.println("exelente");
}else {
    if(notaExamenTotal >=8 && notaExamenTotal <=10) {
        System.out.println("muy bien, puedes mejorar");
}else {
    if(notaExamenTotal >=6 && notaExamenTotal <=8) {
        System.out.println("Bien, no decaigas echales ganas");
    }else {
        if(notaExamenTotal >=5 && notaExamenTotal <=6) {
            System.out.println("tu puedes mejorar");
        }else {
            if(notaExamenTotal >=5 && notaExamenTotal <=6) {
                System.out.println("regular");
            }else{ 
                if(notaExamenTotal <= 5) {
                System.out.println("mal");

                }



            }
            }

            }
        }
}
}
}



public class Nota2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Nota2 objNota2=new Nota2();
objNota2.notaSeguimiento();
}

double notaSeguimientoTotal;

    void notaSeguimiento () {
        double notaSeguimientoTotal=(10);
        System.out.println(notaSeguimientoTotal);




if(notaSeguimientoTotal == 10) {
    System.out.println("exelente");
}else {
    if(notaSeguimientoTotal >=8 && notaSeguimientoTotal <=10) {
        System.out.println("muy bien, puedes mejorar");
}else {
    if(notaSeguimientoTotal >=6 && notaSeguimientoTotal <=8) {
        System.out.println("Bien, no decaigas echales ganas");
    }else {
        if(notaSeguimientoTotal >=5 && notaSeguimientoTotal <=6) {
            System.out.println("tu puedes mejorar");
        }else {
            if(notaSeguimientoTotal >=5 && notaSeguimientoTotal <=6) {
                System.out.println("regular");
            }else{ 
                if(notaSeguimientoTotal <= 5) {
                System.out.println("mal");
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: perdon por el desorden, no se porque quedo copiado asi

Comment: Santiago bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Cuando compartes código, una vez lo haya pegado debes seleccionar todo el código y luego pulsar en la opción **`{ }`** en el panel superior. Por otra parte, se requiere una breve explicación de lo que quieres hacer y del problema que estás teniendo. Ya el título mismo de la pregunta es algo extraño, pues en Java tú no llamas un método **de** una clase a otra clase, sino que, **desde** una clase llamas un método que pertenece a otra clase.

Comment: eso es lo que necesito llamar el metodo de la clase  nota2 a la clase nota        ya que necesito que imprima la respuesta de las 2 clases en el momento de darle correr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para llamar al método de la clase Nota2 en la clase Nota te ha faltado poner la palabra `public` en el método. He visto algunas cosas que tienes de más en tu código y las he comentado.

Clase Nota:

```
public class Nota {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nota objNota = new Nota();
        objNota.notaExamen();
        // Por qué tenías {  } (vacío en el interior) ?

        // Llamar al método de la clase Nota2
        Nota2 objNota2 = new Nota2();
        objNota2.notaSeguimiento();
    }

    /** 
     * Por qué tienes este código que no está haciendo nada?.
     * double notaExamenTotal;
     */

    public void notaExamen() {
        double notaExamenTotal = 6; // Por qué lo tenías entre ( ) ?
        System.out.println(notaExamenTotal);

        if (notaExamenTotal == 10) {
            System.out.println("exelente");
        } else {
            if (notaExamenTotal >= 8 && notaExamenTotal <= 10) {
                System.out.println("muy bien, puedes mejorar");
            } else {
                if (notaExamenTotal >= 6 && notaExamenTotal <= 8) {
                    System.out.println("Bien, no decaigas echales ganas");
                } else {
                    if (notaExamenTotal >= 5 && notaExamenTotal <= 6) {
                        System.out.println("tu puedes mejorar");
                    } else {
                        if (notaExamenTotal >= 5 && notaExamenTotal <= 6) {
                            System.out.println("regular");
                        } else {
                            if (notaExamenTotal <= 5) {
                                System.out.println("mal");

                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Clase Nota2:

```
public class Nota2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nota2 objNota2 = new Nota2();
        objNota2.notaSeguimiento();
    }

    /** 
     * Por qué tienes este código que no está haciendo nada?.
     * double notaSeguimientoTotal;
     */

    // Método public para que pueda ser llamado desde otra clase
    public void notaSeguimiento() {
        double notaSeguimientoTotal = 10;
        System.out.println(notaSeguimientoTotal);

        if (notaSeguimientoTotal == 10) {
            System.out.println("exelente");
        } else {
            if (notaSeguimientoTotal >= 8 && notaSeguimientoTotal <= 10) {
                System.out.println("muy bien, puedes mejorar");
            } else {
                if (notaSeguimientoTotal >= 6 && notaSeguimientoTotal <= 8) {
                    System.out.println("Bien, no decaigas echales ganas");
                } else {
                    if (notaSeguimientoTotal >= 5 && notaSeguimientoTotal <= 6) {
                        System.out.println("tu puedes mejorar");
                    } else {
                        if (notaSeguimientoTotal >= 5 && notaSeguimientoTotal <= 6) {
                            System.out.println("regular");
                        } else {
                            if (notaSeguimientoTotal <= 5) {
                                System.out.println("mal");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En adición, para tu ejercicio, hay muchas maneras de hacerlo más eficiente y con menos código. Puedes tener los métodos de ambas clases en una sola clase, también puedes tener los métodos que reciban un parámetro tipo `int` y cuando llamas a este método, le pasas como argumento el valor deseado.

Tu ejercicio con ambos métodos en la misma clase y que reciban parámetros:

```
public class Nota {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Pasamos el valor como argumento
        notaExamen(6);
        // Pasamos el valor como argumento
        notaSeguimiento(10);
    }

    // Método 1
    // Recibimos el valor como parámetro
    // Nota: un método declarado como estático puede ser accedido o invocado sin la necesidad de tener que instanciar un objeto de la clase.
    public static void notaExamen(int notaExamenTotal) {
        System.out.println(notaExamenTotal);

        if (notaExamenTotal == 10) {
            System.out.println("exelente");
        } else {
            if (notaExamenTotal >= 8 && notaExamenTotal <= 10) {
                System.out.println("muy bien, puedes mejorar");
            } else {
                if (notaExamenTotal >= 6 && notaExamenTotal <= 8) {
                    System.out.println("Bien, no decaigas echales ganas");
                } else {
                    if (notaExamenTotal >= 5 && notaExamenTotal <= 6) {
                        System.out.println("tu puedes mejorar");
                    } else {
                        if (notaExamenTotal >= 5 && notaExamenTotal <= 6) {
                            System.out.println("regular");
                        } else {
                            if (notaExamenTotal <= 5) {
                                System.out.println("mal");

                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Método 2
    // Recibimos el valor como parámetro
    // Nota: un método declarado como estático puede ser accedido o invocado sin la necesidad de tener que instanciar un objeto de la clase.
    public static void notaSeguimiento(int notaSeguimientoTotal) {
        System.out.println(notaSeguimientoTotal);

        if (notaSeguimientoTotal == 10) {
            System.out.println("exelente");
        } else {
            if (notaSeguimientoTotal >= 8 && notaSeguimientoTotal <= 10) {
                System.out.println("muy bien, puedes mejorar");
            } else {
                if (notaSeguimientoTotal >= 6 && notaSeguimientoTotal <= 8) {
                    System.out.println("Bien, no decaigas echales ganas");
                } else {
                    if (notaSeguimientoTotal >= 5 && notaSeguimientoTotal <= 6) {
                        System.out.println("tu puedes mejorar");
                    } else {
                        if (notaSeguimientoTotal >= 5 && notaSeguimientoTotal <= 6) {
                            System.out.println("regular");
                        } else {
                            if (notaSeguimientoTotal <= 5) {
                                System.out.println("mal");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cualquier duda que tengas, estamos para ayudarte. Saludos!.